# How do you have experince in some workplace without actually working there?

Tags: work-environment

I'm badly want to know how it is feel like to be working i some form of working environment, but it is not easy when you are not working for the company. I want to know if any can share their full experience in their workplaces, how you interact with your coworkers, how you annoying are your customers, how badly the organizing in the company,...

This is my first post, if it doesn't fit the community's posting style, I may sorry.

Comment: too broad and not really the sort of question we answer

Comment: @Kilisi and with all due respect sir, we could not answer, even if we tried, :)

Answer (score 2):

> I'm badly want to know how it is feel like to be working i some form
>   of working environment, but it is not easy when you are not working
>   for the company. I want to know if any can share their full experience
>   in their workplaces, how you interact with your coworkers, how you
>   annoying are your customers, how badly the organizing in the
>   company,...

If I understand correctly, you want to know about what it's like to work at a particular company.

When I am interviewing, I always ask to speak with at least one of my future peers at some point during the interview process. What you are seeking are the sorts of questions I ask them. They often feel far more open to discussing the "what's it like to work here?" and "what's it like to work for this boss?" questions.

Answer (score 1):

You won't get a first-hand experience without actually working there. But you can:
 - look up the company on the employers reviews sites like glassdoor.
 - ask around - maybe a friend of a friend has worked (is working) there and you could chat with them for a bit.
 - ask for a "guided tour" (to your future office at least) after you've been made an offer by that company and before you take some time to consider it.

Generally speaking, switching jobs is always a little bit risky and even a perfectly conducted interview with a tour might not protect you from a company culture you don't fit in, though.